# Identify all Windowed Processes

Tags: winapi

I am listing all main/windowed processes currently open - ie every window that shows in the taskbar.

I know I can use both `EnumWindows` and `EnumProcesses` to find this out. Which is the 'correct' and/or efficient method to find all windowed processes?

Both require me to filter through all processes/windows to check that they are windowed processes/main windows and not 'background' processes/child windows.

*Ps: is windowed processes the correct term? I'm looking for all processes that have a main HWND and their icon appears in the Task Bar.

Comment: Raymond Chen had a blog entry a few years ago on how the windows in the Alt+Tab list are chosen, the algorithm for the taskbar is probably similar to that (although as he notes, it's an implementation detail and subject to change). https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071008-00/?p=24863